# IBOutlet variables in a Singleton

Tags: objective-c, singleton, iboutlet

Newbie Warning - I'm trying to create a method for updating displayed information from multiple methods across multiple files. I'm new to Obj-C, but in C this would be trivial - use a function call.

It seems that a singleton design pattern is the solution - create a singleton that updates the displayed information, and the singleton method's available "globally" and it updates the IBOutlet variables. There's one display object and it can be manipulated from any method in the system.

This doesn't seem to work. I suspect it's due to my misunderstanding of how a singleton deals with IBOutlet variables. Perhaps the connections made in IB don't work in singletons?

This must surely be a common problem - accessing the user interface from multiple objects? What's the elegant solution to  this problem?

Answer (score 0):

IB doesn't deal with singleton. But you have some options:

You can call a singleton's method, for the connection IBAction method.

Or similar: in that IBAction method you can broadcast a [notification via NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i).

To inform your UI from different classes, that a change has occurred, create a [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH45-SW1) for your view controller and create a [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html), that conforms to this.

And do yourself a favor: stick to the [MVC pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) cocoa depends on. Otherwise you will fight the Framework, instead of using it.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. However,  as a neophyte, it would be really helpful to get some code examples of your suggestions, if you have the time to offer it. If not, thanks and will explore your suggestions.